# Getting link buttons on the same line

Tags: css, html

I feel like this should be easily searchable but I couldn't find it.

I want link buttons that are next to eachother horizontally:

```
<form action="http://google.com">
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="google">
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="yahoo">
</form>
```

this works, except that they both link to yahoo. I need each button to link differently.

```
<form action="http://google.com">
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="google">
</form>
<form action="http://yahoo.com">
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="yahoo">
</form>
```

this links to different url's however it's rendering one on top of the other.

How do I make them on the same row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it by set `display: inline-block;` to form.

```css
form {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form action="http://google.com">
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="google">
</form>
<form action="http://yahoo.com">
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="yahoo">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick.

```
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    form {
      float: left;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="http://www.google.com">
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="google">
  </form>

  <form action="http://www.yahoo.com">
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="yahoo">
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would be the quick and easy way:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
    <form action="http://google.com" style="display: inline-block;">
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="google">
    </form>
    <form action="http://yahoo.com" style="display: inline-block;">
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="yahoo">
    </form>
</div>
```